# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I looked at many other similar questions, but none seem to work for me.

I am following this example: http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-websocket-integration-example-without-stomp

When, I tried this example alone, it is working perfectly. However, when I tried to integrate it with my main project, it seems to be giving the error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I am just calling index.html directly in my main project.
I am unable to find the source of error.

Following are all the jars in my main project where error is generated:

```
classmate-1.3.3.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-net-3.6.jar
groovy-2.4.10.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.8.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar
javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
json-20140107.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
logback-core-1.1.11.jar
ognl-3.0.8.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
snakeyaml-1.17.jar
spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-websocket-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar
thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.14.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar
unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

[image: This is shown in browser.]

Comment: Please show the Stacktrace

Comment: The error is shown in browser only. No stack trace for it.

Comment: 404 means you are requesting a URL that does not exist on the server